# Logic apps - HTTP connector POST call to API returns 202 and location header but the polling returns 404

Tags: api, rest, http, azure-logic-apps

We have implemented a Logic app to call do a POST call to a third-party API which returns a 202 with location header. The Logic app in the backend automatically polls using the location header resulting in GET request to the third-party provider hoping to receive a 200 response once the processing is complete. However, the GET requests are resulting in 404 errors.

We have tried disabling the check location headers but for some reason Logic apps still continues to send the GET requests and at a faster rate.

[image]

Is there any way to stop the GET request from Logic Apps or should this be the third-party provider's responsibility to handle the polling and not send 404's?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can stop the GET request from your Logic Apps. Basically it totally depends on your workflow. If you are designing a ***stateful* workflow** then I would suggest that not to stop the GET request.

For ***stateful* workflow** all HTTP-based actions follow the standard **asynchronous operation pattern** as the default behavior. Where after an HTTP action calls or sends a request to an endpoint or API, the receiver immediately returns a **"202 ACCEPTED"** response. And the response can include a `location` header which the caller can use to poll or check the status for the asynchronous request until the receiver stops processing and returns a "**200 OK**" success response or other non-202 response.

But if you are designing a ***stateless* workflow**, then caller doesn't have to wait for the request to finish processing and can continue to run the next action. In this case the receiver return the "202 ACCEPTED" response as-is, and proceed to the next step in the workflow execution. **A stateless workflow won't poll the specified URI to check the status**.

You can stop the GET request from your logic app by following any of the two approaches mentioned below.

1. ##### Turn off  **Asynchronous Pattern**  setting.

   You can achieve this by going to the Logic App Designer, on the HTTP action's title bar, selecting the ellipses (**...**) button and setting **Asynchronous Pattern**  to **Off** if enabled.

[image: disable Async Operation]

2. ##### Disable asynchronous pattern in **HTTP action's JSON definition**.

   > In the HTTP action's underlying JSON definition, add the  `"DisableAsyncPattern"`  operation option to the action's definition so that the action follows the synchronous operation pattern. Check this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-workflow-actions-triggers#operation-options) for more information.

Also check this [Asynchronous request-response behavior](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/connectors/connectors-native-http#asynchronous-request-response-behavior) document by Microsoft for more understanding.

Comment: We have tried turning off the asynchronous pattern in the HTTP settings, it does not stop the GET requests after receiving a 202 response and location header. We had raised a support ticket with Microsoft and the engineer monitored the backend logs and regardless of the asynchronous pattern turned on or off the GET request continues. It was classified as standard design/behavior. We've read all the MS documents available and understand the stateful and stateless workflow, but unfortunately we still do face the problem where the GET request is causing 404 due to resource not being availble yet.

Comment: Raise a new request so that someone from the community may help in addressing your issue.